# Update xml attribute using sed (Windows + cygwin and Linux)?

Tags: xml, linux, windows, sed

I need to make an update on an xml file using a sed command and I'm having trouble with this one.. the it needs to run on both Windows (using cygwin) and Linux.

The XML has the following element:

```
...

<parameter name="jersey.test.host" value="localhost" />

...
```

I need to update the value to an arbitrary value, say, "abc".

I tried several commands such as:

```
sed -i "s#\(jersey.test.host\)\s*value="\(.*\)" />$#\1abc#" "C:\file.xml"
```

and also:

```
sed -i "s#<parameter name="jersey.test.host" value=".*" />#<parameter name="jersey.test.host" value="abc" />#"" "C:\file.xml"
```

But no changes are performed to the file when I run the command, which I bet means I'm not matching correctly.

I would not mind if I could do this using awk as well. Whatever works, as long as the same command can be used in both Windows + Cygwin and Linux.

Can anyone help me out with this one? Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sed command includes double-quotes, you should enclose it in single-quotes (or escape double-quotes).

Following command should do the work:

```
sed -i 's#<parameter name="jersey.test.host" value=".*" />#<parameter name="jersey.test.host" value="abc" />#' "C:\file.xml"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `awk` to solve this:

```
awk -F\" '$2=="jersey.test.host" {$4="abc"}1' OFS=\" file
<parameter name="jersey.test.host" value="abc" />
```

To update the file, do:

```
awk -F\" '$2=="jersey.test.host" {$4="abc"}1' OFS=\" file > tmp && mv tmp file
```